# How to select timeframe from https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting-demo week view?

Tags: xpath, robotframework

I am trying to select a timeframe from https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting-demo calendar week view by using the robot framework.

I have tried different xpath-selections with no luck. Below is the latest one. Problem is that it selects always the same column even I change the value of the th[4].

**Mouse Down**  `xpath://thead/tr/td/div/table/thead/tr/th[4]//ancestor::table/tbody//tr[13]//td[2]`

**Mouse Up**  `xpath://thead/tr/td/div/table/thead/tr/th[4]//ancestor::table/tbody//tr[32]//td[2]`

Is there any way to select timeframe on the specific day?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find the matching xpath, by looking at the `"data-date"` Here is a working example, You can change the date accordingly to which one you want to click

```
Click calendar dates
   Open browser   https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting-demo  chrome
   click element  xpath=//*[@id="calendar"]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[contains(@data-date, '2019-06-26')]
   Alert Should be present
```

Results

```
Click calendar dates                                                  | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests.Create Program                                                  | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Tests                                                                 | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Comment: Problem is in the week-view. So you need to go to week view first: 

click button  xpath=//button[@class='fc-timeGridWeek-button fc-button fc-button-primary fc-button-active']

 And there is not possible to select **specific date and time** robot framework will always select same date.